# Android isoDep.getHistoricalBytes() is not working on some Mobile Phones

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, lib-nfc

I am building an android app where I am want to read the historical bytes of the smart card. I am able to read the historical bytes on some mobile phones like Samsung s4(API 21),Sony Xperia E3(API 20), Famoco Fx100(API 17) etc. but not able to get the historical bytes on Sony Xperia tablet Z(API 19). All the devices are NFC Supported and I am using iso Card to read the historical bytes.
Please Suggest me what can I do to get the historical bytes of iso Card for Sony Xperia tablet Z .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: NFC support isn't always that great. Cheap chipsets, cheap support.